# Assets showing on localhost but not heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

Ready for something incredibly confusing?

```
http://localhost:3000/assets/facebook.png
```

This shows just fine. When I push it to heroku, all of my other assets appear except for facebook.png. 
I can't explain it, I can't figure it out. Everything else works just fine.

I've run

```
rake assets:precompile
```

So that isn't the issue. For fun, I deleted Gemfile.lock, bundled, and pushed again. There's nothing that I can see or find that makes me think the image isn't making it up- but it isn't somehow. Ideas, thoughts?

Comment: Double check that the file exists on the server. People sometimes have trouble with file transfer.

Comment: Anything in the logs?

Comment: The log was rather unhelpful - aside from giving me 404 errors. I have a solution but not what I expected for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering another one of my questions! After an hour of searching around I found that rails 4 hates me, or rather, it hates the old code I'm running. I listened to heroku during a push, and it suggested I use gem rails_12factor. I looked at the git here: https://github.com/heroku/rails_12factor and it turns out this addresses my issue. Locally everything works peachy, but when you go production rails is using Nginx. rails_12factor instead routes the assets pipe, which makes more sense anyway.

I hope this solution is of use to someone else out there, because it sure frustrated me for a couple of hours (even before I posted my Q earlier ;) )